# How to disable keyboard input in primefaces calendar

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

How to disable keyboard input in primefaces calendar?

This is my code:

```
<p:calendar id="regDate"  value="#{pc_Program.pendingRep.regDate}" 

pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" tabindex="3" navigator="true"

required="true" maxdate="a"                         

requiredMessage="Please Select Date Of Registration">                       

<p:ajax event="keyup" update="errcalender" />                       

<p:ajax event="dateSelect" update="errcalender" />                          

<p:ajax event="blur" update="errcalender"></p:ajax>                         

<p:ajax listener="#{pc_Program.addBtnEnble}"                            

update="addButton" /></p:calendar> 


<p:message id="errcalender" for="regDate" display="text"></p:message>
```

Answer (score 17):

Use the `readonlyInput` attribute

set it to true

like this

```
<p:calendar readonlyInput="true"
```

Comment: thank you for your solution. But when i used this i am getting another problem. That is i used tabidex in my code. When tab focused to calender field and after selection of date i pressed tab, But its going previous field and on pressing further tabs its toggling betwwen those two fields. What to do..?

Answer (score 0):

i think readOnly="true" will also work.

Comment: No,its not working. readOnly="true" will not assigning selected date to backing bean.